# Are type-inferred variables "optionals" by default in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

In going through Apple's Swift tutorial we are introduced to optionals fairly quickly, informing us that we mark a value as optional by using a '?' character.

The example given is:

```
let optionalInt: Int? = 9
```

It goes on to say:

"To get the underlying **type** (my emphasis, not theirs) from an optional, you unwrap it. You’ll learn unwrapping optionals later, but the most straightforward way to do it involves the force unwrap operator (!). Only use the unwrap operator if you’re sure the underlying value isn’t nil.

```
let actualInt: Int = optionalInt!
```

This is probably excessively nitpicky, but shouldn't it say "To get the underlying **value**..." instead of type?

Anyways, my actual question is about the usage of the question mark. Immediately after the above example we are told:

```
"Optionals are pervasive in Swift, and are very useful for many
situations where a value may or may not be present. They’re 
especially useful for attempted type conversions."

  var myString = "7"                               "7"
  var possibleInt = Int(myString)                   7
  print(possibleInt)                               "Optional(7)\n"

In this code, the value of possibleInt is 7, because myString 
contains the value of an integer. But if you change myString to be
something that can’t be converted to an integer, possibleInt becomes nil.

myString = "banana"                                "banana"
possibleInt = Int(myString)                        nil
print(possibleInt)                                 "nil\n"
```

Why, directly after telling us that optionals are declared with '?', do they give an example that is apparently using an optional without the '?'. 
I tried looking at the documentation and searching other stack overflow answers and maybe I'm just missing something but for some reason I couldn't  find an answer to this apparently simple question.

Comment: On the line `var possibleInt = Int(myString)`, do ALT (option) + CLICK on `possibleInt`, it will show you its type, which is an Optional, *which is written `: Int?`*, which is the type returned by `Int()`.

Comment: If you want the compiler to infer the type, delete the type annotations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perhaps not the clearest example, because type inference is hiding the question mark. If they explicitly declared the type of `possibleInt`, you'd see:

```
var myString: String = "7"                       "7"
var possibleInt: Int? = Int(myString)            7
print(possibleInt)                               "Optional(7)\n"
```

What's happening is the `init(_: String)` initializer on `Int` is what's called a "failable initializer", and it returns an optional `Int`, aka `Int?`.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it's not necessarily the type inference creating the optional, but rather the explicit conversion from String to Int returns an optional?

Comment: That "explicit conversion" is actually an `Int` initializer that accepts a `String` as its single, unnamed parameter, and yes, it is known to return an optional. Therefore, when Apple (confusingly) left out the type annotations, type inference rightly deduced that `possibleInt` is optional, because the return value of `Int(_: String)` is optional.

Comment: @KeithGrout, "Type Inference" does NOT do any kind of conversion, it only detects or infers the type by looking at the surrounding code. In this case, the `Int()` initializer has a "return" type of `Int?` and thus, `possibleInt` is of type `Int?`